# draw jqplot trendline for category axis renderer graphs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I have raised a similar question, however I didnt get any answers so wanna try one more time.

We plotted a graph with CategoryAxisRenderer. The graph is coming fine. We need to add trend line also to this graph as it was done here: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html

I am unable to get that, I have included the trendline.min.js plugin.
However the trend line is appearing as vertical line in the middle of the graph which is incorrect.

can somebody advise how to fix this pls?

```
grdYTcks = ["10","19","10","31","23","0","11","10","9"];
grdXTcks = ["08/26","09/09","09/23","09/26","10/07","10/10","10/22","11/05","11/07"];

$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
plot1 = $.jqplot(grphOneID, [grdYTcks], {
            title: 'Highlighting, Dragging, Cursor and fsdfdsTrend Line',
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: grdXTcks,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%d'
                    },
                    pad: 0
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: -10,
                    max: 110,
                    tickInterval: 10,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%d'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                sizeAdjust: 10,
                tooltipLocation: 'n',
                tooltipAxes: 'y',
                tooltipFormatString: '<b><i><span style="color:red;">hello</span></i></b> %.2f',
                useAxesFormatters: false
            },
            cursor: {
                show: true
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of `grdYTcks` and`grdXTcks` are wrong. Change to :

```
var grdYTcks = [10, 19, 10, 31, 23, 0, 11, 10, 9];
var grdXTcks = ['08/26', '09/09', '09/23', '09/26', '10/07', '10/10', '10/22', '11/05', '11/07'];
```

Here is my test code, I changed the format of `grdYTcks` and`grdXTcks`, also `tickOptions` of `xaxis`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var grdYTcks = [10, 19, 10, 31, 23, 0, 11, 10, 9];
    var grdXTcks = ['08/26', '09/09', '09/23', '09/26', '10/07', '10/10', '10/22', '11/05', '11/07'];
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart_jqplot', [grdYTcks, grdXTcks], {
        title: 'Highlighting, Dragging, Cursor and fsdfdsTrend Line',
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: grdXTcks,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%#m/%#d'
                },
                pad: 0
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: -10,
                max: 110,
                tickInterval: 10,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%d'
                }
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            sizeAdjust: 10,
            tooltipLocation: 'n',
            tooltipAxes: 'y',
            tooltipFormatString: '<b><i><span style="color:red;">hello</span></i></b> %.2f',
            useAxesFormatters: false
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.